# Loading .env dynamically slows down Laravel5.4 app significantly

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am loading .env file for different target environment at run time based on the target environment (development, test, staging or production).

However, I noticed that earlier when I had only one single .envfile and I was not loading the environment file dynamically, Laravel 5.4 was quite fast. Now it become sluggishly slow for every round trip request.

What kind of strategy or mechanism would you suggest to improve my performance while loading .env dynamically?

PS:
I have added following line in to the bootstrap/app.php
This is causing performance issue now for every request.

> $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('environments/.env.local');

Comment: Not sure, it's a gut feeling. Dynamically loading your .env file this way may call an 'artisan optimize' command or at least an 'artisan config:clear'. The .env file holds, per definition, the core settings of your environment, loaded before the laravel booting process.

Comment: I figured this out. Actually the issue is that I am polling an api to determine the environment and then loading them dynamically, and on my API call I had setup a long connection_timeout value. Once I shorten the connection timeout, this got better.